# What is a Poisson Solid?

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I've found on a few places on the internet references to a solid where both Lamé parameters are equal ($\mu=\lambda$), making its Poisson ratio $\nu=0.25$. It seems to be some sort of an 'perfect solid'.

In Maxwell's *On Physical Lines of Force* he calls it

> ...a medium whose elasticity depends entirely upon forces acting between pairs of particles...

He also cites Rankine's *On Elasticity* as a source but I can't seem to find this online. I've tried to find it in Rankine's *Manual of Applied Mechanics* but I can't find it there (Maybe I can't read through the old notation)

Is there any other source that talks about this? Why equate the parameters? What's so special about this?

Comment: I sketched a crystal grid of identical particles and assumed the stress will be related to quasi-static energy shifts in 2-particle potentials due to the various possible displacements. This is a bit of a combinatorics problem so I have not figured it out atm, but this is probably the geometric basis of getting the ratio between Young's modulus and shear modulus $E/K = 3/2$.

Comment: There is a short discussion on the matter in the [*Feynman Lectures on Physics* (Vol.2, Ch. 39-5)](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_39.html#Ch39-S5)

Comment: The relevant part: "In our particular case, $C_{xyxy}=C_{xxyy}$ (it's the Lamé coefficients $\lambda=\mu$). It turns out—as you can perhaps see from the way the calculations went—that these terms are always equal for a cubic crystal, no matter how many force terms are taken into account, provided only that the forces act along the line joining each pair of atoms—that is, so long as the forces between atoms are like springs and don’t have a sideways part such as you might get from a cantilevered beam (and you do get in covalent bonds)."